# AS3 sort string alphabetically

Tags: arrays, string, actionscript-3, sorting

I'm working on a program in which a string contains some words with line breaks between them:

```
Bob
Mohammed
Alfred
Moses
Tom
etc
```

What I'm trying to do is sort it alphabetically as such:

```
Alfred
Bob
Mohammed
Moses
Tom
...
```

As far as I know, it can only be done in arrays, but is it possible to sort items inside a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there isn't a pre-built function to do something, then just make your own function for it.  This is critical to programming in general.

Remember what a string is: it's an array of characters.  In ActionScript 3.0, this isn't quite as true within the language's actual syntax, but you can get around it pretty easily. `String.charAt()` gets you the character at the given index, and you have a whole slew of operations to actually change the order or number of characters in a string.

That being said, since you're just trying to sort individual words, and since they're already one-to-a-line, you can split on the newline character, `"\n"`, which will create an array.  Then you sort that array.  I don't recall off the top of my head whether an array in AS3 will natively sort strings in alphabetical order - you might want to Google that - but I think it does; if not, then that just goes back to what the first paragraph was saying.  Finally you join the array on the same character.

So:

```
var arr:Array = nameString.split("\n");

// sort the different elements within arr here; each one is one name

nameString = arr.join("\n");
```

Comment: Oh, didn't know those functions existed, I'm pretty new to AS3, I only know the basics. I'll keep the first paragraph in mind whenever I'm programming. Thanks alot for your help ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array out of the string by splitting on the newline character (\n), then sorting it, and converting it back to a string by joining the elements with the same newline character:

```
var str:String = "Bob\nMohammed\nAlfred\nMoses\nTom";
var sortedString = str.split("\n").sort().join("\n"));
```